# No sys info on SSH login after disabling password login on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

In an attempt to improve security on Ubuntu 20.04 server I disabled pw login follwing this article: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-disable-ssh-password-login-on-linux/

It works, but the sysinfo does not show up anymore on SSH login:

```
% ssh server
Last login: Sun Mar  6 21:07:05 2022 from 77.2.170.244
```

The steps included:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
PermitRootLogin no
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

How can I reenable landscape-sysinfo ?

Comment: UsePAM no probably disabled several features like motd

Comment: You are right, setting it to yes will bring it back. However the entire purpose of this is then ruled out as it will allow login via pw again. Is there any way around this?

Comment: please let me know what do you mean by sysinfo? what type of info you need to be displayed after login ?

Answer (score 0):

What is taken by one hand can be provided back by the other:

- `UsePAM no`

  disables everything usually handled by PAM. This include this piece of configuration in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

  > ```
  > # Print the message of the day upon successful login.
  > # This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
  > # and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
  > session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
  > session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
  > ```
- One can enable back a part of it with [`PrintMotd yes`](https://manpages.debian.org/sshd_config.5#PrintMotd%7E2):

  > Specifies whether sshd(8) should print `/etc/motd` when a user logs in
  > interactively. (On some systems it is also printed by the shell,
  > `/etc/profile`, or equivalent.) The default is yes.

  This option is specifically set to `no` on systems where `UsePAM yes` is set (such as Debian or Ubuntu) to avoid a double [motd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_(Unix)) on login. It can be enabled back. There won't be the dynamic part (which among other things might display the number of packages that can be upgraded).

So you should change the configuration to also have `PrintMotd yes`.